# How to install vulcan for intel graphics card

Tags: 18.04, graphics, intel

I want to play artifact on Ubuntu 18.04 but every time I try loading it says "failed to initialize Vulkan. Please make sure your driver and GPU support Vulkan."

I have an Intel SandyBridge mobile graphics card. When i enter `sudo lshw -c video` it says my driver is `i915`.

Could anyone tell me what driver I need to install or how to solve the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

On my Kaby Lake i had to run `sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers`
Inspired by the introduction directions here https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

tho i didn't even have this ppa installed. it just led me to check my current `apt list *vulkan*`

Comment: Worked like a charm! No ppa required.

Comment: Worked for me, intel UHD 620

Answer (score 2):

There is no driver to install. Intel graphics only supports Vulkan on Ivybridge and newer chips. Sandybridge is too old.

Comment: Is it possible using mesa?

Comment: No. Mesa is just a provider of the GL APIs. If Vulkan was supported on your CPU, it would already be working.

Comment: Here is compatibility list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulkan_(API)#Compatibility

(Skylake and up offer Vulkan 1.0 and 1.1 support, Ivy bridge to Broadwell support 1.0, Sandy bridge not supported)

Answer (score -1):

```
 sudo apt-get install vulkan-tools vulkan-validationlayers libvulkan1 libvulkan-dev mesa-vulkan-drivers
```

after that give the below command :

```
vulkaninfo
```

intel HD 520 support vulkan on linux